# URISyntaxException different message in JDK19 & JDK20

Tags: java

If i am running below code in jdk19 and jdk20 different exception message is coming

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI("http://www.goo gle.com");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("Bad URI" + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Hello World" + uri);

    }
```

In jdk19 - `Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://www.goo gle.com`

In jdk20 - `Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 14: http://www.goo gle.com`

In jdk19 the index is coming as 7 but in jdk20 the index is coming 14 for same URI.

Expecting same index should come in the exception message.

Comment: Best guess: JDK20 is giving you the index in just the authority (`www.goo gle.com`) and JDK19 is giving you the index in the whole string (including `http://`). Such minor implementation details can change between releases, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Based on Jorn's plausible explanation, this difference is due to a bug fix in Java 20.  And there's **no practical way** to get both versions to give you the same answer.

Comment: You don't actually have any basis for that expectation. The message isn't specified anywhere, so there is nothing to rely on.

Comment: @user207421 With most exceptions, you'd be right, but for the URISyntaxException, there is a specification (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [URI constructor specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)), it states that a URISyntaxException can be thrown.

What you see as the exception text, is the result of a [getMessage() call](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URISyntaxException.html#getMessage()), and that defines the structure of the text. After the colon is the input string, in your case `"http://www.goo gle.com"`, and the index given should be an index into exactly that input string. The offending space character is at index 14 in that string, so the JDK 20 implementation is correct, and JDK 19 is wrong in stating the index to be 7.

But, relying on such fine details of exception instances is never a good idea.